# How do i put more arguments in input function??? (beginner)

Tags: python

Say I have a variable `computer_guess` and `player_answer` that is assigned a value.

I wanna be able to do this:

```
player_answer = input("is this your number?",computer_guess)
```

I want the (`"is this your number?"`) to be on the same line with the variable `computer_guess`.

Is this achievable??

Thanks :)

Comment: Look into string formatting, e.g. `input("Is this your number - {0}?".format(computer_guess))`, see [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use `str.join()`:

```
player_answer = input(" ".join(("is this your number?", computer_guess)))
```

You could also just concatenate:

```
player_answer = input("is this your number?" + computer_guess)
```

For both of those solutions, `computer_guess` needs to be a string.  If it is not, use `str(computer_guess)` instead.  You could also do this:

```
player_answer = input("is this your number? {}".format(computer_guess))
```

That last will work for any type.

Comment: @AChampion: Thank you for pointing that out; I have corrected it.

Comment: thank you very much. I have used the last line of code you suggested, the variables are not strings. I just wanted to ask you about the .format part. could you give me a bit of information about it?

Comment: [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) is a string method that is used for inserting certain things inside a string.  For example, `"My name is {}; my hair color is {}".format("Zondo", "brown")` would result in `"My name is Zondo; my hair color is brown"`.  In format strings, braces are used to mean that something else is supposed to go here.  You can also number your braces: `"My name is {0}; my hair color is {1}".format(...)`.  You can also use keys: `"My name is {name}; my hair color is {color}"`.  In that case, you need this: `"...".format(name="Zondo"...)`